# Help me learn to speak Susan's language

Tags: cipher

Susan was born with an extreme case of the rare communication disorder, "dyscryptia", which has enthralled neuroscientists and computer scientists alike from all 6 corners of the globe. She is one of only a dozen recorded cases. This puzzling disorder is unique in that in each of the twelve cases, the disorder manifests itself in a distinct manner; the common denominator being that the disorder always affects communication letter by letter.

I met Susan just yesterday night at the local pizza parlor as she was playing a beautiful piece on the place's piano. I went up to her to compliment her playing, but of course, my message didn't get across. She pointed at a square board on top of the piano consisting of many common English words coupled with their translations, and I used it to repeat myself.

In the conversation that ensued, I found myself enchanted by this strange woman. I would like to prepare for the next time we meet, so that I may speak her language and offer a more comfortable conversation.

I remember a few useful details. Maybe my memories could serve as a Rosetta Stone, a bridge between our languages.

Susan referred to herself as "Nntog", and to her language as "Susubam". Following is a list of words and their translations that I can recall.

```
| Time | Good | Have | Give | Want | Take | Make | Know | Last | Long | Next | Come |
| Cvry | Vdsk | Iwam | Peal | Xohq | Ulpy | Nlpr | Yclh | Mtmf | Acus | Scrh | Rbrh |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| I | A | You | He | She | It | The | Of | On | And | But | Or | Right | Add | Near |
| I | A | Njt | Mm | Amx | Cc | Bmy | Uu | Cc | Ore | Wov | Gg | Apobl | Ehe | Sfsf |
```

There were more.. but I can only remember so much.

Oh, and as I was leaving, she told me, "Hgjqz cqjos njmh yizaj, cm'i hgqccnkb rapf am clp." She must have forgotten for a moment that I don't speak Susubam?

Comment: "It" and "On" both translate to "Cc"? What a strange language.

Comment: I would love to hear the last sentence from Susan pronounced.

Comment: +1 - one of the most brilliant surrounding stories I've seen!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT:** Finally **solved** last part. 
 Decrypted Sentence:

> Sorry about your pizza, it's probably cold by now.

Also, I got curios about previous sentence which was edited. In case anyone wondering it is decrypted as:

> I have to get home. Maybe I'll see you next week.

**ORIGINAL**:

I solved the encrypting part, however decoding isnt that easy. Still working on that part but this is my *partial answer*.

> Each letter has a value as following a=1,b=2,c=3...,y=25,z=26

Encryping works as following;

> Assume word is A,B,C,D then ecrypted text is (A+B)%26, (B+C)%26, (C+D)%26,(D+A)%26

Lets try with examples:

> Good = 7,15,15,4 = (7+15)%26,(15+15)%26,(15+4)%26,(4+7)%26 = 22,4,19,11 = Vdsk
>  Give = 7, 9, 22, 5 = 16, 5, 1, 12 = Peal 
>  On = 15,14 = 3,3 = cc
>  Of = 15,6 = 21,21 = uu

Decrypting:

> So all the words which have only 2 letters must encrpyt into a double letter word (such as aa,bb,cc..). However, Susan's last sentence has 2-letter word(am) which doesnt fit this rule. 
>  
> If this is not a mistake, I'm assuming we should evaluate all words in a sentence together and probably gonna ignore signs('.).

Comment: Perhaps when doing a sentence, instead of wrapping the encoding on each word, you pick from the first letter of the next word?

Comment: Yes I thought so and trying it.

Comment: This is correct of course. Next time I'll try to make it more difficult :)